# PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, usb, bluetooth

My problem is with my laptop HP COMPAQ TC4200: I can't get the Wifi to start, even after following advice from the forums.

Hardware data:

```
Description: Notebook
     Product: HP Compaq TC4200 (PV984AW # ABE)
     Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
     Release: F.0F
```

Tests performed:

```
00: 16: 6F: 3E: CB: 47
************************************************** **************
* -network DISABLED
                 Description: Wireless Interface
                 Product: PRO / Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection
                 Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 4
                 bus information: pci @ 0000: 02: 04.0
                 logical name: eth1
                 Version: 05
                 series: 00: 16: 6f: 3e: cb: 47
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                 configuration: broadcast = yes driver = ipw2200 firmware 1.2.2kmprq driverversion = = ABG: 9.0.5.27 (Dec 12 2007) latency = 64 link = no maxlatency = 24 mingnt = 3 multicast = yes wireless = IEEE 802.11bg
                 resources: irq: 21 memory: d8000000-d8000fff

$ lsusb
00: 16: 6F: 3E: CB: 4700: 16: 6F: 3E: CB: 47
Bus 001 Device 010: ID ffee: 0100
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 15CA: 00c3 Textech International Ltd. Mini Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 03f0: Hewlett-Packard 011D Bluetooth 1.2 Interface [Broadcom BCM2035]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

---

Besides all I got light blue bluetooth, but the psyche wifi off, look at the bios and enabled, aztualice the bios and comprove this on.

Appears in the Network program in ubuntu but only with physical direcion uba is 00: 16: 6F: 3E: CB 47 has a button but not activated is disabled.

**New information:**

```
$ rfkill list all 
1: phy0: Wireless LAN 
    Soft blocked: no 
    Hard blocked: yes 
3: hci0: Bluetooth 
    Soft blocked: no 
    Hard blocked: no 

$ dmesg | grep ipw 
[ 10.781580] libipw: 802.11 data/management/control stack, git-1.1.13
[ 10.781585] libipw: Copyright (C) 2004-2005 Intel Corporation
[ 11.088738] ipw2200: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 2200/2915 Network Driver, 1.2.2kmprq
[ 11.088744] ipw2200: Copyright(c) 2003-2006 Intel Corporation
[ 11.089003] ipw2200: Detected Intel PRO/Wireless 2200BG Network Connection
[ 11.887902] ipw2200: Radio Frequency Kill Switch is On:
[ 11.901564] ipw2200: Detected geography ZZR (14 802.11bg channels, 0 802.11a channels)
[ 25.840067] ipw2200: Failed to send POWER_MODE: Command timed out.
[ 38.948053] ipw2200: Failed to send POWER_MODE: Command timed out.
```

Comment: Can you please translate your question into English, or remove the Spanish translation?! That would make it much more easier to read and understand and also shrinks down the content of your question (:

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the interface is shown as 'disabled' when the wireless switch or key combination is set to turn off the wireless. Do you have button #3 here? Is it set to enable wireless?

[image]

You might try removing the keyboard module:

```
sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

Any improvement?

If this doesn't work, I suggest you try the live DVD or USB for a more receny Ubuntu version; 14.04 or 14.10 where the module *hp-wmi* might be working better.

Comment: When I click on button # 3 off the Bluetotch.
in the network program I see but this is not available, we pulse and immediately disconnects.
I think you have to install something and not that ?.

thank you very much

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: rfkill list all
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? lsb_release -d Thanks.

Comment: Description: Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: Also probe with other versions is the same.
If I insert a USB Wifi feels the same.
with windows if it works, but do not want windows.
That occurs to you, Mister.

Comment: As I do, I'm inexperienced.

Comment: Are you confirming that in Ubuntu 14.10, rfkill list all still shows 'hard blocked:yes'?

Comment: More information put up, not put that to the best way so you can read it better, sorry.